# html name tag array type different ways of naming the element

Tags: html, arrays, input, tags

In a project, I have to clone my input elements. I searched in google and found different ways to do this. One way was to create html name tag input array. But the naming convention was different in different sites.  Like,

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="row i_bike_servicing">
        <div class="col-md-2 p-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="from_place[]">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 p-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="from_date[]">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another way I found was:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="row i_bike_servicing">
        <div class="col-md-2 p-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bike_servicing[from_place][]">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 p-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bike_servicing[from_date][]">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And also like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="row i_bike_servicing">
        <div class="col-md-2 p-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="from_places[][from_place]">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 p-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="from_dates[][from_date]">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is the meaning of these three different approaches of name tag array syntax? In which case, we have to select which one naming convention or all of these are same?

Reference: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/any-better-way-to-transform-this-html-input-array

Answer (score 0):

```
from_place[], simple array, example :

from_place[0] = 'A',
from_place[1] = 'B',
from_place[2] = 'C'
= from_place = 0 = A
               1 = B
               2 = C
```

---

```
bike_servicing[from_place][], you can store data with `from_place` as the first key and each of them has a unique child key, example :

bike_servicing[from_place][0] = 'A',
bike_servicing[from_place][1] = 'B',
bike_servicing[from_place][2] = 'C'
= bike_servicing = from_place = 0 = 'A'
                              = 1 = 'B'
                              = 2 = 'C'
```

---

```
from_places[][from_place], lets say you can store data with unique key and `from_place` is the name for each key, example :

from_places[1][place] = 'A',
from_places[2][place] = 'B',
from_places[3][place] = 'C'
= from_places = 1st place = 'A'
                2nd place = 'B'
                3rd place = 'C'
```

Some reference : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multidimensional-arrays-in-php/